# Why not able to find second new event using inotifyd in c language

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, inotify

I am trying check new event created or deleted in the specific directory.
If event is created then need to do some operation using thread and this thread should be in initiate wile loop .
Main thread should look for another event creation or deletion.

I have developed application , but I could not able to second event is created or not.
Code flow is always in child  thread.

Please find below code :

```
    #include <errno.h>
   #include <poll.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <sys/inotify.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #define PATH_MAX        4096
   #define O_RDONLY      00

    int main()
   {
       //char buf;
       char buf[4096]
           __attribute__ ((aligned(__alignof__(struct inotify_event))));
       int fd, i, poll_num;
       int *wd;
       nfds_t nfds;
       struct pollfd fds[0];
       char *device_path = "/home/home/test";
       ssize_t len;
       const struct inotify_event *event;       
       int counter=0;
       char getdata[10];
       char devname[PATH_MAX];
       char *filename;
       int thread_ret = 0;
       static pthread_t inotify_pthread;
       
       

       /* Create the file descriptor for accessing the inotify API */

       fd = inotify_init1(IN_NONBLOCK);
       printf("fd = %d",fd);
       if (fd == -1) {
           perror("inotify_init1");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

      

       /* Mark directories for events
          - file was opened
          - file was closed */

       
           wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, device_path,
                                     IN_OPEN | IN_CLOSE | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);
           printf("wd = %d ",wd);
           if (wd == -1) {
               fprintf(stderr, "Cannot watch '%s': %s\n",
                       device_path, strerror(errno));
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }
       

       /* Prepare for polling */

       nfds = 1;
   

       /* Inotify input */

       fds[0].fd = fd;
       fds[0].events = POLLIN;

       /* Wait for events and/or terminal input */

       printf("Listening for events.\n");
       while (1) {
           poll_num = poll(fds, nfds, -1);
           if (poll_num == -1) {
               if (errno == EINTR)
                   continue;
               perror("poll");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           if (poll_num > 0) {             
               if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {

                   /* Inotify events are available */

                   len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));

                   if (len == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) {
                        perror("read");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    if (len <= 0)
                        break;

                    

        for (char *ptr = buf; ptr < buf + len;
                    ptr += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + event->len) {

                   event = (struct inotify_event *) ptr;
        if ( event->len ) {

           
                    

               /* Print event type */
                if (event->mask & IN_CREATE){
                   printf("IN_CREATE: \n");
                    if (event->len){
                        counter++;
                   printf("IN_CREATE: created file name : %s  , counter no = %d \n", event->name,counter); 
                      
                      

                    thread_ret = pthread_create(&inotify_pthread, NULL, event_read_data(),NULL);
   
                        if (thread_ret < 0) {
                        printf("can't create inotify thread");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                   


                    }
                   
                   }                
                   else if (event->mask & IN_DELETE){
                        counter--;
                       printf( "IN_DELETE : Deleted File name %s , counter no = %d \n", event->name,counter );
                       
                   }
                }

                printf("counter number : %d \n",counter);          
             
           }
                   
               }
           }
       }

       printf("Listening for events stopped.\n");

     

       close(fd);

       free(wd);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   event_read_data(){

    while(1){
       printf("Child Thread");
       sleep(3);
    }
   }

  Compiled like below:
  gcc fine_name.c -lpthread
```

Comment: What is `event_read_data`? Does it return a function pointer? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That is just thread creation.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that there is a function definition for `event_read_data` at the bottom. Initially I misinterpreted that as function call due to missing return type and paramter list. That function does not return anything. Using the non-existing return value to create your thread is undefined behaviour.

Comment: If your compiler does not complain about using `event_read_data()` in thread creation, you should turn up warnings. You should get warning about implicit function declaration or in case you just did not show it, for wrong parameter type.

Comment: No, I can able to compile the code and i am always prints child thread print.

Comment: In b/w  new events created then it should be print main thread logs . but it is not happening

Comment: In the code you show, `event_read_data` never returns. If you use it in `pthread_create(&inotify_pthread, NULL, event_read_data(),NULL);` you will be stuck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229246/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-gnk).

Comment: I have add added headers. Could you please check.

Comment: I have added all my code . For me also compiled successfully with warning. And I am trying to understand , where I have done wrong.

Comment: Please respond in the chat. That makes it easier to follow.